# assigning attributes to data frame variables in place using *apply functions

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to set the attribute "mean" to the variable mean for all variables in a data frame (I'm actually working with applying proper attributes from a Stata file to data frames, but this is essentially the problem). Using a `for` loop, this works:

```
test <- mtcars
for(var in seq_along(test)) {
  attr(test[[var]], "name") <- mean(test[[var]])
}

str(test)
'data.frame':   32 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ mpg : atomic  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
  ..- attr(*, "name")= num 20.1
 $ cyl : atomic  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
  ..- attr(*, "name")= num 6.19
```

However, my best attempt using apply and the super assignment operator does not work:

```
test <- mtcars
apply(test, 2, function(var) {
  attr(var, "name") <<- mean(var)
})

 mpg        cyl       disp         hp       drat            
 20.090625   6.187500 230.721875 146.687500   3.596563...   

str(test)
'data.frame':   32 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ mpg : num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
 $ cyl : num  6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
 $ disp: num  160 160 108 258 360 ...
```

I clearly don't fully understand apply and the super assignment. Can I do this using one of the apply functions and/or dplyr?

Comment: Unlike `for` loops, `*apply` functions operate within their lexical scope rather in the global environment. I really don't see how this is related to `dplyr`, but you could check the `setattr` function in the `data.table` package instead.

Comment: this is antinomic: apply functions do not operate in place. Your solution is fine if you want to avodi duplicating your data frame.